# How to convert CSV data to file type in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, csv, filesystems

I want to convert JSON data to CSV and then convert that CSV data to CSV file type and then use that file type object to upload on firebase.
I converted JSON to CSV but I am unable to convert that data to CSV file type object to upload on firebase as a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert CSV to BLOB

```
var CSV = [
    '"1","val1","val2"',
    '"2","val1","val2"',
    '"3","val1","val2"'
  ].join('\n');

window.URL = window.webkitURL || window.URL;
var contentType = 'text/csv';
var csvFile = new Blob([CSV], {type: contentType});
```

Per the Firebase documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files), you should be able to use `Blob` to store it in Firebase.

```js
var file = ... // use the Blob or File API
ref.put(file).then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
});
```

Comment: thanks for helping.I'll update the status after checking the method

Comment: Set let me know.